# How do I JOIN two datasets in Palantir Foundry within a code workbook?

Tags: join, pyspark, palantir-foundry, foundry-code-workbooks

Hi I know this is a basic question but I'm new to Foundry and Pyspark, please help!
I need to JOIN two datasets in a Code Workbook of Palantir Foundry using 3 columns (two are named the same in both but one uses a different name within the datasets) I'm not sure how to do this. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [pyspark documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.join), you can use a list of columns for the "on" argument (the join keys). If you were joining two datasets (df1 & df2), where df1 had join keys ["a", "b", "c"] and df2 had join keys ["a", "b", "c2"], I would do something like this:

```
df1.join(df2.withColumnRenamed("c2", "c"), on=["a", "b", "c"], how="left")
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the PySpark documentation that @kate provided, you just need to specify either

1. a string representing a column, which must exist on both tables
2. a list of strings representing multiple columns, which again must exist on both tables
3. a Column expression, which allows you to do some more complex logic on your join condition. For example, you may want to join to tables on the condition that the `date` column in table A is in between `date_before` and `date_after` in table B. This would look something like `df_a.join(df_b, on=((df_a.date < df_b.date_after) & (df_a.data > df_b.date_before)))` so you have a lot of flexibility here in terms of how you can join datasets